# How to use open function with path include space

Tags: python, tkinter

I'M try to make a program that works with drag file into gui and create a hash code for it. But if path of file has space in it, then it goes error. How can i fix this

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\c9947515\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\c9947515\Desktop\Phyton\pythonProject1\dosya hash.py", line 19, in on_drop
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '{C:/Users/c9947515/Desktop/Wire Text.txt}'
```

```py
import tkinterdnd2 as tk
import tkinter as tk2
import hashlib

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("File Hash Calculator")
root.geometry("400x150")

root.drop_target_register(tk.DND_FILES)

def on_drop(event):

    file_path = event.data
    # Dosya yolunu oku ve dosya içeriğini oku
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
       data = file.read()

    # Dosya içeriğine göre SHA1 değerini hesapla
    sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest()
    # SHA1 değerini inputbox'a yazdır
    input_box.insert(0, sha1_hash)

# Dosya sürükleyip bırakıldığında tetiklenecek fonksiyonu ata
root.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", on_drop)

# Açıklama yazısı oluştur
label = tk2.Label(root, text="Drag and drop a file to calculate its SHA1 hash:")
label.pack()

# Giriş alanı oluştur
input_box = tk2.Entry(root)
input_box.pack()

# Pencerenin çalışmasını sağla
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why does it look like the filename is surrounded by `{}`?

Comment: i thinked about it but how can i apply it. because i take file path from drop file event. And it's a variable.

Comment: I fixed it with replace

    file_path = file_path.replace("{", "")
    file_path = file_path.replace("}", "") Thanks @quamrana

Answer (score 1):

`{` and `}` are being added to your paths.
If you use `file_path = file_path.replace("{", "").replace("}", "")`
then it will not handle files with `{` or `}` anywhere in the filename. Use `removeprefix` and `removesuffix` instead to avoid this problem.

This will work:

```py
import tkinterdnd2 as tk
import tkinter as tk2
import hashlib

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("File Hash Calculator")
root.geometry("400x150")

root.drop_target_register(tk.DND_FILES)

def on_drop(event):

    if event.data.startswith('{') and event.data.endswith('}'):
        file_path = event.data.removesuffix('}').removeprefix('{')
    else:
        file_path = event.data    
    # Dosya yolunu oku ve dosya içeriğini oku
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
       data = file.read()

    # Dosya içeriğine göre SHA1 değerini hesapla
    sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest()
    # SHA1 değerini inputbox'a yazdır
    input_box.insert(0, sha1_hash)

# Dosya sürükleyip bırakıldığında tetiklenecek fonksiyonu ata
root.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", on_drop)

# Açıklama yazısı oluştur
label = tk2.Label(root, text="Drag and drop a file to calculate its SHA1 hash:")
label.pack()

# Giriş alanı oluştur
input_box = tk2.Entry(root)
input_box.pack()

# Pencerenin çalışmasını sağla
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is incorrect; it will butcher paths which legitimately contain `{` or `}` anywhere within them. The `strip` solution avoids that (though applying it blindly would still wreck paths which correctly end with `}` or `{`).

Comment: @tripleee
`it will butcher paths which legitimately contain { or } anywhere within them`
*incorrect* it will remove *one* `{`  from the start and  *one* `}` from the end if the string starts with `{` *and* ends with `}`

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the `.replace` variant but I see now that your actual code is correct and that my warning merely repeats yours. Perhaps the exposition could be clarified to better highlight the correct approach.

Comment: sorry @tripleee
i had been using inconsistent newlines

Comment: Oh I see; your resistence to proper punctuation exacerbated the problem. I have edited to fix that, and added an elaboration about the proper fix.

Answer (score 1):

It is added by the underlying TCL interpreter when there are spaces in the string.  You can remove them using `.strip("{}")`:

```py
file_path = event.data.strip("{}")
```